# Some question ideal of variety

Tags: commutative-algebra

For an affine variety $X=V(x^{2}+y^{2}-1, x-1)$, I found the ideal of $X$,  $I(X)=\langle x-1,y\rangle$. But I don't know $I(X)=\langle x^{2}+y^{2}-1, x-1\rangle$.

Comment: I've converted the $<$ and $>$ to `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **false** that $I(X)=\langle x^2+y^2-1,x-1\rangle$. The ideal $\langle x^2+y^2-1,x-1\rangle$ is equal to $\langle x-1,y^2\rangle$, because $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ can be removed, but $\langle x-1,y^2\rangle$ is not equal to $\langle x-1,y\rangle$.

This is fine, though - have another look at the [Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz):
$$I(V(J))=\text{rad}(J)$$
where $\text{rad}(J)$ is the [radical of the ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_ideal) $J$. In general, it is only true that $\text{rad}(J)\supseteq J$.

Do you see why the radical of $\langle x-1,y^2\rangle$ is equal to $\langle x-1,y\rangle$?

**Hint:** it may help to first prove that
$$\text{rad}(J_1+J_2)=\text{rad}(\text{rad}(J_1)+\text{rad}(J_2))$$
for any ideals $J_1$ and $J_2$.

Comment: Thanks Zev Chonoles. since $<x-1,y>$ is a maximal, I knew that the radical of $<x-1,y^{2}>$ is equal to $<x-1,y>$.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: Can you please explain why $\langle x^2+y^2-1,x-1\rangle$ is  equal to $\langle x-1,y^2\rangle$ and not $\langle x-1,y\rangle$. In J.Smith book "Introduction to AG" I saw same example, but the $I(X)=\langle x-1,y\rangle$