# A derivation problem related with Hidden Markov Chain

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

I encountered the problem here([Hidden Markov Chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#Probability_of_an_observed_sequence))

It is like this:

The task is to compute, given the parameters of the model, the probability of a particular output sequence(observed sequence). This requires summation over all possible state sequences:
The probability of observing a sequence(output sequence)

[image]

of length L is given by

[image] **(*)**

where the sum runs over all possible hidden-node sequences

[image]

For more specific information on the related information, refer to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#Probability_of_an_observed_sequence)

**My problem is:**

How the **(*)** equation can be derived?

It seems to be according to Total  Probability  Theorem. But this does not make sense to me.

Comment: Does $P(Y) = \sum_X P(Y \; X) $ makes sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Your notations are awful but this is indeed nothing else than the law of total probabilities: you consider two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space with values in sets $E$ and $F$ respectively and you are asserting that for every $y$ in $F$,
$$
\mathrm P(Y=y)=\sum\limits_{x\in E}\mathrm P(Y=y\mid X=x)\mathrm P(X=x).
$$
Compare with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications) for $A=[Y=y]$.

Comment: Do you mean that $E$ is countable or finite?